# Django. Revert previous page

Tags: python, django

I have an image_delete django-controller. I use it on several pages. I need that after deleting the image, the controller returns me to the previous page. but I get an error. what is the problem? How to fix it?

views.py

```
class ImageDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Picture 
    template_name = 'adminapp/pet/pet_image_delete.html'
    @method_decorator(user_passes_test(lambda x: x.is_superuser)) 
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

urls.py

```
path('delete/image/<int:pk>/', adminapp.ImageDelete.as_view(model=Picture), name='image_delete')
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkTIK.png)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want `self.request`:

```py
def get_success_url(self):
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

Comment: Then I get the error "quote_from_bytes () expected bytes"